# finding second space and remove in R

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

I would like to remove second space of several names (after `sp.`) in R using `tidyverse`

My example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("Araceae sp. 22", "Arecaceae sp. 02"))
```

My desired output

```
x
Araceae sp.22
Arecaceae sp.02
```

Any suggestions for me, please?

Comment: Would you consider that to be second space or the space after `sp.`?

Comment: sr my question is not clear, the space after `sp.`. I think it is also the second space, isnt it?

Comment: `sub("sp. ", "sp.", df$x)` You might have a second space without `sp.` Should that also be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `sub` to capture the one or more characters that are not a spaces followed by space (`\\s+`) and another set of characters not a space and replace with the backreference of the captured group

```
df$x <- sub("^(\\S+\\s+\\S+)\\s+", "\\1", df$x)
df$x
[1] "Araceae sp.22"   "Arecaceae sp.02"
```

---

Or we can use `str_replace`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
    mutate(x = str_replace(x, "^(\\S+\\s+\\S+)\\s+", "\\1"))
```

Comment: whether `tidyverse` help me to solve that like `sub` function doing here now?

Comment: @Anh you can use `str_replace` as in the updated